# Absolute value and Argument of a complex number with trignometric function?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, absolute-value

I have a complex number $z = -\alpha_1 \alpha_2 \sin^{2}(\theta/2)+ i\alpha_3\sin(\theta/2)|\sin(\theta/2)|$, where $\alpha_i \in \Re, i \in 1, 2, 3.$ I wish to find the absolute value and argument of this complex number. Whether the absolute value is $\sqrt{\alpha_{1}^2\alpha_{2}^2+\alpha_{3}^2}$ and whether the argument is well-defined? For finding the argument, Should I resort to case by case analysis?

Comment: `Whether the absolute value is ...` $\;z=0$ for $\theta=0\,$, so that formula is missing something. `Should I resort to case by case analysis` Yes, there are just two cases..

Comment: So $|z| = \sqrt{\alpha_{1}^2\alpha_{2}^2+\alpha_{3}^2}$ if $z \neq 0$ else if $0$ for $z = 0$. The $\arg(z) = \pm \frac{\alpha_3}{\alpha_1\alpha_2}$ depending upon the sign of $|\sin(\theta/2)|$ or $\arg(z) $ is undefined if $|\sin(\theta/2)|=0$. Is this right?

Comment: No, I think it's not the idea in the comment. The idea is that the formula is wrong and this fact was exposed by means of an counterexample. You have to redo it from the start. Maybe your formula for the absolute value can be "tuned" by some factor $\sin^2(\theta/2)$.

Comment: I forgot the factor $\sin^{2} \theta/2$ in the absolute value.

Answer (score 3):

$z = -\alpha_1 \alpha_2 \sin^{2}(\theta/2)+ i\alpha_3\sin(\theta/2)|\sin(\theta/2)|$

For the absolute value:

$\vert z\vert^2=z\bar z=\alpha_1^2\alpha_2^2\sin^4(\theta/2)+\alpha_3^2\sin^2(\theta/2)|\sin(\theta/2)|^2$

$\vert z\vert=\sin^2(\theta/2)\sqrt{\alpha_1^2\alpha_2^2+\alpha_3^2}$

For the argument, [$\arg z=\text{atan2}\left(\Im(z),\Re(z)\right)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computation),

we have to consider $\sin(\theta/2)/\vert\sin(\theta/2)\vert$, that it is $\pm1$ depending on the value of $\theta/2$

$\arg z=
\begin{cases}
 \text{atan2}\left(\alpha_3,-\alpha_1\alpha_2\right)&\text{for}&4k\pi\leq\theta\lt(4k+2)\pi,\;k\in\mathbb Z\\\
 \text{atan2}\left(\alpha_3,\alpha_1\alpha_2\right)&\text{for}&(4k+2)\pi\leq\theta\lt(4k+4)\pi,\;k\in\mathbb Z
\end{cases}$